# Best way to create a custom lookup

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I would like to know what the best way is to create a custom lookup for a field in my table, my situation is as following:

I have `Form A` which has a datasource to `Table A`, a field on that datasource has a lookup method:

```
public void lookup(FormControl _formControl, str _filterStr)
{
    changeCompany(companyInfo.DataArea)
    {
        super(_formControl, _filterStr);
  }
}
```

The field has an EDT, which has an relation to a Table.

The table has multiple fields, 1 of them is `field: GroupType (Enum)`, with 2 options: Suppliers and Customers.

Form A is showing all records, both with Suppliers and Customers, but i would like to filter on the records with only has the value Suppliers in Column C.

Based on the information above, what is the best way to create this custom lookup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create *Related field fixed* relation between your tables

```
TableB          = TableB.Id
Enum::Suppliers = TableB.GroupType
```

Or [create a custom lookup](http://devexpp.blogspot.com.by/2012/02/dynamics-ax-custom-lookup.html)

and set a range for field `GroupType`.